# Remove query string from redirected URL with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using the following code to redirect traffic to a spesific page (this traffic is coming via google from an old site which used to use my servers ip)

```
RewriteRule ^viewtopic.php?/?$ http://www.myurl.org.uk/ [L,R=301]
```

As I understand it this `^viewtopic.php?/?$` should strip away the query string but it isn't working. Any help appreciated.

Example URL

```
http://www.myurl.org.uk/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=44207&start=2265
```

Output when redirected

```
http://www.myurl.org.uk/?f=3&t=44207&start=2265
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You were close to the answer... You have the `?` on the wrong side. Put it on the redirect side to strip off the query string:

```
RewriteRule ^viewtopic.php http://www.myurl.org.uk/? [L,R=301]
```

In a 301 redirect, mod_rewrite will normally append the full query string.  But placing a `?` at the end of your rewritten URL without a corresponding `[QSA]` ("querystring append") flag will instruct it instead to use the blank query string you supplied.