# How to remove the query string from htaccess RewriteRule. Given solutions don't seem to do it

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

[Remove query string from redirected URL with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956475/remove-query-string-from-redirected-url-with-htaccess)
asks the question how to remove the query string on redirect.
The answer given (add a ?) is exactly what is given in the Apache manual. However, it does not seem to work (yes, it's probably me).
Using the same example

Starting URL:

```
http://www.myurl.org.uk/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=44207&start=2265
```

Rewrite code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^viewtopic.php http://www.myurl.org.uk/? [R=301]
```

Output URL:

```
http://www.myurl.org.uk/?f=3&t=44207&start=2265
```

I was hoping for:

```
http://www.myurl.org.uk/
```

This has been tested on htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Many thanks