# Rewrite several index.php? to root

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

how to rewrite all this in .htaccess:

```
/index.php
/index.php?FeaturedMode=online
/index.php?MembersMode=online
/index.php?MembersMode=top
/index.php?lang=en
/index.php?lang=pl
/index.php?skin=tmd062_new
```

to root (/)?

I found this code:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it works only for index.php and all I get is: /?lang=en etc.
I need more general solution :)
Thanks.

Comment: Are there other potential query string values which should _not_ be rewritten to root, or is this just a wholesale rewrite to `/`?

Comment: With the rewrite rule you just posted, the only problem is that it fails to remove the query string?  To force it overwritten with a blank query string, use `/$1?`

Comment: Hi Michael, no - no other query string values. I'll try your solution.

Comment: I'm still getting /?lang=pl. How to rewrite it to / ? (without index.php, just /?lang=pl to / )

Comment: Make sure your browser isn't caching your previous redirect (Firefox especially is bad about this). Try a different browser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove query string from redirected URL with htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956475/remove-query-string-from-redirected-url-with-htaccess)